# Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition - Analyze Code Coverage Option is Missing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-coverage, mstest

Currently i am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Previously i have been using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and there is a option available for generating Code Coverage Results under `Test>Analyze Code Coverage>All Test`

Here in Visual 2017 Community Edition There is no option avaiable for **Analyze Code Coverage** and The Option is only avaiable for Code Converage Window under `Test>Windows>Code Coverage results`.

How to find **Analyze Code Coverage** in Visual Studio 2017 Community ?

Comment: One alternative is DotCover from JetBrains
https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's VS edition comparison tool (under Testing Tools)](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) Code Coverage functionality is only available in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

[image]

EDIT: I ran into the same issue with VS 2017, and I have had good luck using [AltCover](https://github.com/SteveGilham/altcover) as an alternative